# select * from tables with common characters in their names

Tags: mysql

I have table names that begins with common characters, e.g.

```
mytab_user
mytab_group
mytab_mode
mytab_blah
```

I have a large number of similar tables. Is there any command line in mysql that will do something like,

```
select * from mytab_*;
```

and show me all the data from all these tables at once.

Comment: Do these tables all have the same structure? If not this is going to be a big query *and* you'll have to tell us the table structures.

Comment: No, they don't have the same structure. Is there any command like this for tables with same structure ?

Comment: You could join all of these tables right off the bat and rename it something like tab_tables. You would then be able to run any type of query that you want on the table "tab_tables". (also, you would want to make sure tab_tables is a temporary table)

Comment: Not an easy one. I was thing along the lines of first selecting all table names matching mytab_* from the system tables and then trying something with that set, but that's still not easy. With differently structured tables you have to spell everything out and use UNIONs. BTW I can hardly imagine a useful query like this if your tables are very different.

Comment: When you really want to do this, ask yourself if you really need a database at all for whatever you're doing. If yes, I can only say "you're doing it wrong!"

Comment: If the tables had the same structure you could populate an answer table with all of their data. Since they have a unique structure you would have to modify their structure or select just what they have in common to make the answer set the same in order to populate a common table, otherwise it simply cannot be done.

Comment: You can use [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysqldump.html).

Comment: If you're even asking this question, it implies that you do not have a good understanding of how relational databases work. It is very unlikely that you actually want to load very single bit of data from your DB into memory at once. (If you do, just query them all seperately). Most likely, you probably want to get data from one table that is linked to data in another table, and so on. If that's what you're after, you need to be looking in how to do `JOIN` queries.

Comment: @Spudley I don't discard your statement that I don't have a good understanding of how relational DBs work. I am reading the data entries in all these tables for a DB that has already been created. I wanted to know if there is a command like that which will make my life easier, because I have to read these DB a number of times on the command line...

Comment: @fancyPants Yes, I have asked myself and the creator of the DB that I need a DB. Please don't judge that I am doing it wrong based only on this question.

Comment: @ThomasFonseca Thanks. It simply can't be done is also an answer I am looking for. In this case, I will not waste anymore time searching around for an answer. That is precisely why I asked this question. +1 for you.

Comment: you could get all tables names with this: (SELECT table_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
  WHERE table_schema = 'yourDB') but i don't think you can use the result in a SELECT

Comment: What you are asking is not possible with SQL only, it needs to be done using store procedure... I'll check this later... regards

Answer (score 3):

Use [stored procedure](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/stored-programs-defining.html) to do a task. Below is an example to do that.

```
    use mydatabase;

    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS showalldata;

    delimiter //
    CREATE PROCEDURE showalldata()
    BEGIN
      DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
      DECLARE a CHAR(255);
      DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR (
        SELECT table_name
        FROM information_schema.tables
        WHERE table_schema = DATABASE()
            AND table_name like 'mytab\_%'
        ORDER BY table_name ASC);
      DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

      OPEN cur1;
      read_loop: LOOP
        FETCH cur1 INTO a;
        IF done THEN
          LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;

        SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT * from ', a);
        PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
        EXECUTE stmt;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

      END LOOP;

      CLOSE cur1;
    END //
    delimiter ;

    CALL showalldata();
```